# Three.mesh got partially blocked by model

Tags: three.js

I was intended to fill the space between two THREE.Lines with some color. I tried to use THREE. It looks fine from [some angles below the model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDCc3.png), but if looking from top to bottom, the mesh area got partially blocked ([the image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfNyW.png)). The other THREE.js objects, such as the red points and red lines are not affected by model while the Three.mesh gets screwed up. The following is my code for the Three.mesh:

```
  // push vertices 
  geom.vertices.push((new THREE.Vector3()).fromArray(borepoint));
  // add faces to mesh
  for(let i =0; i < geom.vertices.length-2; i++){
    for(let j = i + 1; j < geom.vertices.length-1; j++){
      for(let k = j + 1; k < geom.vertices.length;k++){
        geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(i,j,k));
      }
    }        
  }
  const fillMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geom , new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    color: 0x2f92d7,
    transparent: false,
    opacity: 0.5,

  }));
```

Does anyone has any idea about this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try 
depthTest:false, transparent:true, opacity:1 in the material?

Comment: depthTest: false solved the problem. Thank you very much! can you put it as an answer? so that i can close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the problem turned out to be .depthTest. The Object is getting hidden behind the terrain geometry due to z-buffering (aka depthTest).

Disabling .deptTest on the blue objects material, fixed it.

Setting .transparent = true on the material,  flags to be rendered second, in the transparency pass. Without it being set, drawing order may or may not be correct and the problem could still remain.

One way to ensure that it will always render on top, is to have the geometry in a different scene which you renderer.render after the terrain scene but that may be overkill for this scenario.